# Can you suggest ways to assure client data confidentiality in a SaaS product managed by yourself?

Tags: database, data, software-as-a-service

I am designing a multitenant SaaS platform where the database will hold information for different clients.

The application consists of an Angular frontend and a REST API Backend.

Some of the clients want to assure the confidentiality of their data, so even though we accessed the database tables as admins we couldn't read it.

As you can see below, the client 1 doesn't care about having their data in clear text, but client 2 expects some kind of confidentiality (encryption)

```
 id   event         client_id
------------------------------
  1   some info        1
  2   x233r3fs34       2
  3   more info        1
  4   6u6ytgg343       2
```

Can you suggest ways to achieve something like this, or any other approach?

Obviously if we encrypted the information in the backend we would have the key, so having the ciphered data and the key is equal to nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer really depends on what you're doing with the data on the backend. If you're just storing blobs of data for your client, you can:

- Encrypt it on the front-end with a key the back-end never sees.
- Send the encrypted data to the backend.
- Retrieve the encrypted data from the backend.
- Decrypt it in the front-end again.

See for instance [S3 client-side encryption](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/UsingClientSideEncryption.html).

If you want to actually be able to interpret the data on the backend, you're (just about) asking the impossible: you can't both be able to read the data and not read the data. The "just about" here is [homomorphic encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphic_encryption), but that's almost certainly not commercially viable for whatever your business model is.

Answer (score 3):

There needs to be further discussion with the client about their actual requirements.

An extreme solution would be to go full end-to-end encryption, which would mean that your backend only sees encrypted data. But that means your backend can't do anything with the data other than storing it – any processing and querying would have to happen client-side. (Yes, homomorphic encryption exists, but it is computationally expensive and entirely irrelevant for all practical purposes.) This works well for some use cases like instant messaging or backup storage, but usually isn't appropriate for business processes. The cost of implementing such a solution is probably not worth it, even if it were feasible for your use case.

Encryption at rest can provide slightly better assurances than no encryption at all. You correctly note that if you have both the encrypted data and the key, then you can decrypt it. This cannot be a hard security barrier that would defend against malicious admins. But it can still protect against accidental disclosure, and if an attacker accesses a key that might leave relevant traces for later analysis. Encryption at rest in the form of full-disk encryption is industry standard, but row-level encryption is not due to the difficulty of appropriate key management.

Hot tip: if clients have extremely difficult requirements that are exceedingly difficult or expensive to satisfy, they might not be worth having as a client. I love data protection and security, but some problems simply cannot be fixed via technical means such as encryption.

Answer (score 1):

Although [amon's answer is very good from a product-technical perspective](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/438261/4), you may also need to consider other types of controls on the data. Having documented processes and procedures for granting, reviewing, and revoking access to production data, moving data out of production environments to lower environments or preventing such movement of data, and auditing system access and changes are just a few examples of procedural controls that you could put into place.

Industry standards like ISO 27001 and the AICPA's Trust Services Criteria may give some ideas for the types of controls in place. The [Cloud Security Alliance's Consensus Assessment Initiative Questionnaire](https://cloudsecurityalliance.org/research/cloud-controls-matrix/) pulls in technical and process controls from a number of standards and offers some self-assessment tools that may help you think through specific risks and mitigations.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestions Thomas. The case here is that we are providing a cloud solution that stores information that could be sensitive for some clients. They don't want as as service providers to have any access to that information, considering we could take advantage of it in our benefit, providing strategic consultancy services to other clients using that data (obviously anonimizing it). Since they don't "trust" us, they won't trust our procedural controls and demand a technical solution.

Comment: @codependent I've worked on cloud services that store highly sensitive data, including proprietary data, PII, and PHI. Regardless of your technical controls, you will need some procedural controls as well. Expecting 0 access to the data for the organization maintaining the system is an unrealistic expectation - encryption-at-rest, encryption-in-transit, encrypting on store or read for key data elements, and procedural controls all come together to protect the data.